# Angluar4 Without Node Modules

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a website for my company. I need to be able to run the app without the node_modules directory.

I am on a multi-dev team and do not have the ability to check-in/commit the the entire node_modules directory to version control.

Is there a way I can pre-compile @angular-core/types, and ngtools into a few js files?

The end result is, another dev can grab the latest code, edit/and or run without having the node_modules directory on their machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't develop angular app without node_modules.
Node and Npm are essential in angular.

You don't have to commit entire `node_modules` folder, it should be ignored (.gitignore). Every team member has to install node_modules on his machine in order to run the app.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will use Vue.js instead.